# View border gradient animation

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

is it possible to achieve this in SwiftUI [image: animation]

I know how to put a border on a view, I just dont know how to ajust it so it gets the animation.

hope you guys can help with that

So I have tried something liked

```
.overlay {
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                .stroke(LinearGradient(gradient: gradient, startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
                    .onAppear {
                        animation.toggle()
                    }
            }
            .animation(.linear(duration: 4).repeatForever(autoreverses: false), value: animation)
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I actually came up with a better solution, which also means that I got rid of the `GeometryReader`.

```swift
struct ShineBorderAnimation: View {
    @State private var gradient: [Color]
    @State private var startPoint = UnitPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    @State private var endPoint = UnitPoint(x: 0, y: 2)

    init(gradient: [Color] = [Color.white, Color.yellow, .white]) {
        self.gradient = gradient
    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0)
                .stroke(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: gradient),
                                       startPoint: self.startPoint,
                                       endPoint: self.endPoint),
                        lineWidth: 2)
        }
        .onAppear {
            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 2.0).repeatForever(autoreverses: true)) {
                self.startPoint = UnitPoint(x: 1, y: -1)
                self.endPoint = UnitPoint(x: 0, y: 1)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Let's start with a view that animates a yellow band:

```
struct Shine: View {
    var body: some View {
        TimelineView(.animation) { context in
            let period = 2.0
            let t = 2 / period * context.date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate.remainder(dividingBy: period)
            LinearGradient(
                gradient: .init(stops: [
                    // Important: Don't use .clear. After masking
                    // (later in this answer), the colors come out
                    // better with .yellow.opacity(0).
                    .init(color: .yellow.opacity(0), location: t + 0.3),
                    .init(color: .yellow, location: t + 0.4),
                    .init(color: .yellow, location: t + 0.6),
                    .init(color: .yellow.opacity(0), location: t + 0.7),
                ]),
                startPoint: .topTrailing,
                endPoint: .bottomLeading
            )
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like this:

[image: a gold band animation from top right to bottom left]

Now let's overlay that on some other view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("You did it.\n\nGood job.")
            .padding()
            .overlay {
                Shine()
            }
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}
```

It looks like this:

[image: some text with the animated yellow band overlaid]

Finally, let's mask the overlay to just a thin border:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("You did it.\n\nGood job.")
            .padding()
            .overlay {
                Shine()
                    .mask {
                        Color.clear
                            .border(.black, width: 2)
                    }
            }
            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
    }
}
```

It looks like this:

[image: some text with an animated yellow border]

Comment: I like the approach of this solution, im a little concern of all thise small location calculations, a bit hard to understand. seems more like a hack 

Answer (score 0):

Instead of applying a border you can apply padding to the foreground and then add a background layer that you can fill completely with the gradient.

To animate it, I found that switching start and end point didn't work very well. But switching layers in a `ZStack` is not bad:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var animation = false
    let gradient = Gradient(colors: [.yellow, .gray])

    var body: some View {
        Color.white
            .padding(4)
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            .background {
                ZStack {
                    if animation {
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(
                                LinearGradient(
                                    gradient: gradient,
                                    startPoint: .topTrailing,
                                    endPoint: .bottomLeading
                                )
                            )
                    } else {
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(
                                LinearGradient(
                                    gradient: gradient,
                                    startPoint: .bottomLeading,
                                    endPoint: .topTrailing
                                )
                            )
                    }
                }
            }
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 2.5).repeatForever(), value: animation)
            .onAppear {
                animation.toggle()
            }
    }
}
```

To see what's going on in the background, change `Color.white` to `Color.clear`!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your solutions.

For now i have implemented this which I think is the best solution for now. I stile have to figure out how to get rid of the GeometryReader.

```
struct Animation: View {
@State private var isAnimating = false

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        Rectangle()
            .fill(Color.white)
            .overlay(
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0)
                    .stroke(Color.yellow, lineWidth: 2)
                    .mask(
                        Rectangle()
                            .fill(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.clear, .white, .clear]), startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))
                            .offset(x: isAnimating ? geometry.size.width : -geometry.size.width)
                    )
            )
            .onAppear {
                withAnimation(.linear(duration: 2).repeatForever(autoreverses: true)) {
                    self.isAnimating.toggle()
                }
            }
    }
    .frame(width: 300, height: 100)
}
```

[image]